# How to represent NULL to Neural Network

Tags: c#, neural-network, encog

I have large sets of data but somewhere in columns there is missing data either on purpose if it doesn't exist so it's null or it is missing so that field is null.Should I represent this value as number that I don't use in my data ranges like -1 or something else?

Comment: Just a comment, but NULL is a different concept to Missing. I'd represent null data with null, and missing data with some other representation (Data.Null or Data.Missing is an enum I've used). Using a value that is potentially within your data range (even if it isn't right now) is never a great idea as your allowed values may change over time (but NULL or MISSING should always be NULL or MISSING!)

Comment: @dash Thanks for clearing that out, that's why I specified that data is missing somewhere and doesn't exist somewhere else. I was just wondering are there any numbers that are commonly used for that or is it matter of preferance.

Comment: @user1010609: that depends on your data. Are there any number values that are otherwise unused? If not, you'll have to use a bigger/more complex datatype (perhaps a struct containing your number plus a "missing" flag)

Comment: @jalf Range is fairly simple, 0 - 10000(max), but if I use negative numbers I would have to change activation function aswell?

Comment: You could always use Int32.MinValue then. It is indeed a matter of preference! However, as a caveat, we used to represent missing values with -1. Then -1 became a perfectly valid number in our data sets, so we had to update all of the previous values (and display logic etc). It's always good to focus on something that is independent of the data so you never run into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default(T); You can also use Nullable's..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx

Check out my reporting class for Missing Data

https://net7ntcip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/89621#1751861

https://net7ntcip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/89621#1751850

Comment: I know about making a type nullable but in Neural network inputs values have to be presented as numbers,and I was just wondering are there any numbers that are commonly used for that or is it matter of preferance or did I missundrestood you?

Comment: both, if you have a Nullable type then you have a number with no value :) e.g. `if(! given.HasValue) //Determine your own here